# Django - Custom handler500 not working despite following docs

Tags: python, django

I followed the docs step-by-step and searched for a solution everywhere but my custom `handler500` won't work. I use Django 2.2 with Python 3.8.

Here's my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # some urls
]

handler500 = "path.to.my.handler"
```

my handler:

```
def handler500(request, exception=None, *_, **_k):
    print("yeah I got called")

    return render(request, "my_template.html", {
        "exception": exception
    })
```

my view:

```
def example_view(request):
    # I tried all of these

    return HttpResponseServerError()
    return HttpResponse(status=500)
    raise Exception("There was an error")  # This just shows: "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator." in the browser.
    raise HttpResponseServerError()  # This shows the same message as above.
    a_typo  # This typo also shows the same message as above.
```

Why doesn't ANY of these errors show my template? The handler didn't get executed at any time. The `print()` function never got called.

**EDIT**
I setup a 404 handler and tested it, it worked perfectly. Why not the 500?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FOUND THE SOLUTION**

I had a setting called `DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` set to `True`. This seemed to disable my custom handler. It works perfectly now.

Comment: You can also try this with `DEBUG = False`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks [Juan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6883240/juan-garc%C3%ADa), it is necessary set `DEBUG = False`. Doc [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/views/#the-500-server-error-view)

> If DEBUG is set to True (in your settings module), then your 500 view will never be used, and the traceback will be displayed instead, with some debug information

Answer (score -2):

Quoting Django documentations

> If you implement a custom view, be sure it accepts a `request` argument and returns an `HttpResponseServerError`.
>   You have to return an `HttpResponseServerError` in your `handler500`.

A very simple way to implement all this is just include in your views

```
def handler500(request, exception, template_name="my_template.html"):
    response = render_to_response("my_template.html")
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

This way you don't need to change anything in your URLConfs. This approach does require that your template is at the top of the root template folder. Maybe name it "500.hml" and it would jump up to the top.